# Update after CTE: The multi-part identifier "MyCTE.SomeField" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have following SQL query in my sql-server:

```
WITH SampleCTE1 AS ( ... ), 

MyCTE(SomeField) AS ( SELECT SomeField FROM ....) 

UPDATE SomeTable WITH (serializable)
   set SomeColumnInSomeTable = MyCTE.SomeField  
   where SomeFieldInSomeTable = 112
   if @@rowcount = 0
   begin
      insert into SomeTable.....
   end
```

> The multi-part identifier "MyCTE.SomeField" could not be bound.

Can you help me remove this error ?
Btw, I have a `sql-server-2012`. Is it ok to use `MERGE` ? In some places I did read that I shouldn't use it due to bugs.  What do you think ?

Comment: Can you get rid of the "..."s and post everything?  [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only reference your common table expression(s) in the statement after the last cte, so you will have to repeat it to use it again for the following `insert` (or use `merge`) .

You also have not joined or accessed `MyCte` in your `update` statement.

```
WITH SampleCTE1 AS ( ... ), 

MyCTE(SomeField) AS ( SELECT SomeField FROM ....) 

UPDATE SomeTable WITH (serializable)
   set SomeColumnInSomeTable = MyCTE.SomeField  
   from SomeTable 
     inner join MyCTE
       on SomeTable.SomeId = MyCte.SomeId
   where SomeFieldInSomeTable = 112;

   if @@rowcount = 0
   begin;

    ;WITH SampleCTE1 AS ( ... ), 

    MyCTE(SomeField) AS ( SELECT SomeField FROM ....) 

      insert into SomeTable.....
   end;
```

Comment: Ok, but what about MERGE ? Is it safe ?

Comment: @HaskellFun It depends on a couple of things, such as your current version, service pack, and CU -- and other things in your database like Indexed Views etc. [Use Caution with SQL Server''s `MERGE` Statement - Aaron Bertrand](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)

Comment: So, in really I should do in above way, don't you ? It is safe, simple and reliable.

Comment: @HaskellFun I agree. One way has much more that needs to be considered than the other. Unless there is a compelling reason to use `merge`, I wouldn't.

Comment: @HaskellFun you will have to repeat it to use it again for the following insert

Comment: There is some problem. I have also in `insert into` refer to MyCTE, but it returns: `Invalid object name: MyCTE`. I wouldn't like to create temporary table.

Comment: Thanks. If sqlserver deal with optimizations ? For example, there is no need to compute this two times.

Comment: @HaskellFun The cte will not cost anything if that part of the procedure is not executed.

Answer (score 0):

`MyCTE` is not referenced in `UPDATE`. It should be

```
...
UPDATE SomeTable WITH (serializable)
   set SomeColumnInSomeTable = MyCTE.SomeField 
FROM SomeTable
{LEFT/ RIGHT / INNER}JOIN  MyCTE ON ...
```